# django + postgres and select distinct

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am running django with postgres and I need to query some record from a table, sorting them by rank, and get unique entry in respect of a foreign key.

Basically my model is something like this:

```
class BookingCatalog(models.Model):
   .......
   boat = models.ForeignKey(Boat, verbose_name=u"Boat", related_name="booking_catalog")
   is_skippered = models.BooleanField(u'Is Skippered',choices=SKIPPER_CHOICE, default=False) 
   rank = models.IntegerField(u"Rank", default=0, db_index=True)
   .......
```

The idea is to run something like this

```
  BookingCatalog.objects.filter (...).order_by ('-rank', 'boat', 'is_skippered').distinct ('boat')
```

Unfortunately, this is not working since I am using postgres which raises this exception:

**SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions**

What should I do instead?

Answer (score 5):

[The distinct argument has to match the first order argument](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). Try using this:

```
BookingCatalog.objects.filter(...) \
                      .order_by('boat', '-rank', 'is_skippered') \
                      .distinct('boat')
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that I do this is to select the distinct objects first, then use those results to filter another queryset.

```
# Initial filtering
result = BookingCatalog.objects.filter(...)

# Make the results distinct
result = result.order_by('boat').distinct('boat')

# Extract the pks from the result
result_pks = result.values_list("pk", flat=True)

# Use those result pks to create a new queryset
restult_2 = BookingCatalog.objects.filter(pk__in=result_pks)

# Order that queryset
result_2 = result_2.order_by('-rank', 'is_skippered')

print(result_2)
```

I believe that this results in a single query being executed, which contains a subquery. I would love for someone who knows more about Django to confirm this though.

Answer (score 0):

..ordering by -rank will give you the lowest rank of each duplicate, but your overall query results will be ordered by boat field

```
BookingCatalog.objects.filter (...).order_by('boat','-rank','is_skippered').distinct('boat')
```

For more info on, refer to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)
 including for Postgres